# How to find $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln^2{x}\ln^2{(1-x)}}{2-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

How to find

> $$
> I=\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\left(x\right)\ln^{2}\left(1 - x\right) \over 2 - x}
> \,{\rm d}x
> $$

**My idea:**

Let $x=1-t$, then

> $$
> I
> =\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\left(1 - x\right)\ln^{2}\left(x\right) \over 1 + x}\,{\rm d}x
> $$

I can't proceed any further. I can't remember that Math SE has this similar problem already posted.

this integral problem is from This Euler Sums  :
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}}} \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k - 1}}}}{k}} } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k - 1}}}}{{{k^2}}}} } \right) =  - \frac{{23}}{{1440}}{\pi ^4}\ln 2 + \frac{1}{{18}}{\pi ^2}{\ln ^3}2 - \frac{1}{{18}}{\ln ^5}2 - 4L{i_4}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)\ln 2 - 8L{i_5}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right) + \frac{1}{{12}}{\pi ^2}\zeta \left( 3 \right) + \frac{{27}}{4}\zeta \left( 5 \right)$$

when I deal this series,then we must solve this integral .

Thank you.

Comment: I used [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+1+%28ln^2%28x%29+*+ln^2%281-x%29%29+%2F+%282-x%29) to get 0.964264

Comment: @mvw, anyone can use WA.And it is .0964264...

Comment: Yes almost anyone, that is why I did not put this comment into an answer. But fun aside, I did look at the WA results to rule out that it might have an easy solution. So this seems to be a harder nut involving series expansion, numerics or reformulation to use some non-elementary function.

Comment: And you're right about the missing .. (+1)

Comment: I think it's just too bad a difficult problem like this only give +50 rep. No wonder the kings of integration don't show up. **Just a Random Comment**

Comment: For the derivation, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.12155).

Answer (score 8):

Just a possible approach to solving this.

Let $1-x=e^{-z}$ Then $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln^2(1-e^{-z})z^2}{1+e^{-z}}e^{-z}dz=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{\infty}z^2\ln^2(1-e^{-z})e^{-(k+1)z}dz\\ =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k I_k$$ where $$I_k=\int_{0}^{\infty}z^2\ln^2(1-e^{-z})e^{-(k+1)z}dz$$ Perhaps these later integrals can be calculated.

$$I_k=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ij}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^2e^{-(k+j+i+1)z}dz\\=\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ij}\frac{2}{(k+i+j+1)^3}$$ So, $$I=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{2}{ij(i+j+k)^3}$$

Comment: How did you integrate the $I_k$?

Comment: I used the expansion of $\ln(1-x),\ x\in (-1,1)$

Comment: It's good  job! +1

Comment: I need more help to understand steps (-4) to (-3) and (-3) to (-2). And is there a "+1" missing in the denominator of (-1)? (-k) = (last k-th formula).

Comment: The $+1$ is "missing" because I changed the lower limit of $k$ from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Since:
$$[x^n]\log^2(1-x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right)=\frac{2H_{n-1}}{n},\tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}I &=& \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{2H_{n-1}}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n \log^2 x}{1+x}\,dx = \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{2H_{n-1}}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2 e^{-(n+1)t}}{1+e^{-t}}dt\\ &=& 4\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}-\frac{1}{(n+2)^3}+\frac{1}{(n+3)^3}-\ldots\right)\\&=&4\sum_{s=3}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^s}{s^3}\sum_{n=2}^{s-1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n},\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
that is (in disguise) the same identity found by Samrat Mukhopadhyay.

Answer (score 4):

Here a closer form for this integral

$$
I=−\frac{13}{2}\zeta_2\zeta_3 +\frac{2}{3}\zeta_2\ln^3 2   +\frac{15}{2}\zeta_5+\zeta_4\ln2-\frac{1}{15}\ln^5 2+8\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: It seems to me numerically correct. +1. Could you give us any details?

Answer (score -1):

Using Mathematica, I found the answer below, which matches numerically.
I wonder if this can be simplified. Mathematica couldn't. Do you have a reason to expect there to be a simpler form?

$$
8 (\zeta (3)-3) \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,1,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+4 \zeta (3) \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,0,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+12 \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,2,0)}(1,1,2,-1)-4 \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,3,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,4,0)}(1,1,2,-1)-12 \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,0,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+2 \left(6 \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,1,0)}(1,1,2,-1)-3 \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,2,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,3,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,2,0,0)}(1,1,2,-1)-\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,2,1,0)}(1,1,2,-1)\right)+\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,2,2,0)}(1,1,2,-1)-\frac{2}{3} \pi ^2 \left(-2 \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,1,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,2,0)}(1,1,2,-1)-\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,0,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+\text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,1,0)}(1,1,2,-1)+\log (4)\right)-4 \zeta (3) \log (4)-\frac{1}{90} \pi ^4 \log (2)+24 \log (2)
$$

Comment: oh,maybe have simpler form?

Comment: @math110 Well, that's what I'm asking you. Is there a reason to think that there exists a simpler form?

Comment: @math110: What's the source of this problem?